# editor for web development - python, html and javascript on ubuntu

Tags: editor, text-editor

I use gedit in Ubuntu (dual monitor) for web development in python,html,js.

its working good and fast enough, but with lots of file open, and file switching and saving reduces productivity. so I am looking for alternative.

I am not looking for heavy eclipse for my slow dual core machine. so, what other option do I have ? I am ok with gui or non gui.  my feature requirement is , line numbers, code highlight for python,html,js. auto/smart indenting, fast , auto saving, and good for more than 20 file open and switching. i am not worrying about learning curve.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its like cutting a rose with a garden scissor. :p
NetBeans supports all these .

Answer (score 2):

If you're serious about not being worried about the learning curve... than I would recommend trying Vim or GVim. Once you get used to it it'll save you loads of time.

It has all the features you want either build-in or easily scriptable since it can be completely modified to your wishes.

The autosave for example: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Auto-save_current_buffer_periodically

Answer (score 0):

[Netbeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Python)? I've recently been blown away by it. Maybe it is too eclipse like still.

Answer (score 0):

[Geany](http://www.geany.org/) is a good lite IDE to investigate.

Otherwise, I recommend spending some time to configure `vim`.